# Один presenter и несколько view

Tags: android, шаблоны-проектирования, mvp

Можно ли как-либо связать один Presenter и несколько View? Есть много примеров, где в активити (View) создаётся Presenter, и после этот Presenter обновляет эту же активити. А мне нужно сделать так, чтобы создавался Presenter в одной активити (и получал в ней от `Intent`'a данные), а после получения ответа от сервера этот Presenter открывал другую активити и выводил ответ в ней. Возможно ли это сделать? Не противоречит ли никаким принципам MVP? И если возможно, была бы благодарна за пример, как примерно это можно реализовать...

Comment: Не знаю насчёт того кошерно ли это - один презентер для нескольких View (думаю вполне кошерно), но сделать просто - сделайте презентер синглтоном и всё.

Comment: ну так и передайте из вашего презентера данные во вторую активити, зачем, а во второй активити будет свой презентер, зачем такие сложности с одним?

Comment: вообще советую использовать https://github.com/Arello-Mobile/Moxy она не даст вам слишком сильно уйти в сторону от mvp.

Comment: в классическом MVP одна вью = один презентер. К тому же ваш презентер не должен знать ничего о среде выполнения, т.е. он не может стартовать никакие активити самостоятельно, он вообще не должен знать, что работает в андроид приложении, в нем не может быть ссылок на контекст. Передавайте данные и запускайте активити как и всегда делали это в андроид приложении - в активити используя интенты.